# Read JSON String to Find Facebook Links

Tags: json, facebook, parameter-passing

I can´t find a solution to reading the amount of likes from a facebook page. It is not possible to pass the variable $name correctly. Would highly appreciate help!

```
  name=$(grep "NAME_OF_FACEBOOK_PAGE" output3.txt |
echo "$name"
curl -s "http://graph.facebook.com/?ids=https://www.facebook.com/$name/likes" -o output3.txt
cat output3.txt  |  grep  "\"likes\"" -A1 -B0
```

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to read the number of likes of a certain page, why don't you use

```
https://graph.facebook.com/{page_name}?fields=id,name,likes,talking_about_count
```

Your call to the Graph API is incorrect.